# Axis2 application Weblogic managed server

Tags: server, weblogic, apache-axis, managed

Have created Webservice and deployed in weblogic admin sever its working as expected. But customer wants this to be deployed in weblogic managed server and in the deployment there is no error. But not able to access service. Anyone assists on what should be done to make this working in managed server.

Comment: Server version Weblogic10.3. Creating war file by placing aar files by adding service list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebLogic admin console to deploy and target your application to the managed server. If the application is already deployed, just update the targetng mode to include the managed server.

Comment: Yes, While deploying it there is no error i.e pointing the target managed server but service is not working by that case. Is there specifically to do in the war creation.My  Understanding is that Admin server provides required jar files but managed server does not. Is anything to configured in war creation?